# Proof verification: $diam(E) = diam(\overline{E})$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

Since $E \subseteq cl(E) $, then it is immediate that diam $(E) \leq $ diam(cl($E))$.
I only need to show that assuming diam $(E) < $ diam(cl($E))$ will lead to contradiction then I can conclude that diam $(E)= $ diam(cl($E))$.

So suppose that diam(cl($E$)) > diam($E$).     Then there exist a $p,q \in $ cl($E$)     such that $ d(p,q) > $diam($E$).  By def of cl($E$), there exist a sequence of $\{p_n\}, \{ q_n \}  \in E$ such that $ p_n , q_n  \to p, q ~~  $  respectively as $ n \to \infty $.

Also note that by triangle inequality ,we have

$$ (1) ~~~~~~ d(p,q) - [d(p,p_n) + d(q,q_n)] \leq d(p_n,q_n)   \text{  for all } n.$$

Since $ p_n, q_n \to p,q $ , we have $ d(p,p_n) + d(q,q_n) \to 0 $ as $ n \to \infty$.

Since $ d(p,q) > $ diam(cl($E$)), we can choose some $p_n, q_n $ such that 
$$  d(p,q) - [d(p,p_n) + d(q,q_n)] > \text{diam}(E).$$
Then by (1) above, we have 
$$ d(p_n,q_n) > \text{diam}(E),$$
a contradiction.  Thus the result holds.

Is my proof correct? and is there a shorter way to do this?? thank you very much.

Comment: It looks correct,if somewhat lengthy. Clever use of the sequential definition of closure.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 Thank you, I can only think of this, do you know if there is a shorter proof??

Comment: Working on it.........lol

Comment: Under the relation $(1)$, I think you wanted to say that $d(p,q)>diam(E)$, no ? Then, I don't really see why you can choose $p_n,q_n$ s.t. $d(p,q)-[d(p,p_n)+d(q+q_n)]>diam(E)$.

Comment: @Surb thank you for the input, $ d(p,q) > $ diam(E) is the result of my assumption.  I think can conclude what you ask since I can choose $p_n,q_n$ so that $ d(p,p_n) + d(q,q_n) < \frac{d(p,q) - diam(E)}{2}$, then it follows from this the result you ask, or at least that's what I think.

Comment: @Surb My bad for not spotting the error,but your basic reasoning still looks ok. I'd check it carefully again.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 it's ok man, but does my explain to "Surb" seem correct to you? It looks correct to me since I thought eventually $d(p,p_n) + d(q,q_n)$ would approach 0 so you can make the expression $ d(p,q) - (d(p,p_n) + d(q,q_n) ) $as close to $d(p,q)$ as you like.

Comment: @Khoata Looks ok to me too. I posted a shorter proof of the second step below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose that $x,y\in\operatorname{cl}(E)$ and fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then, there exist $a,b\in E$ such that
\begin{align*}
d(a,x)<&\,\frac{\varepsilon}{2},\\
d(b,y)<&\,\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.
\end{align*}
The triangle inequality then implies that $$d(x,y)\leq d(x,a)+d(a,b)+d(b,y)\leq d(x,a)+\underbrace{\sup_{\hat a,\hat b\in E}d(\hat a,\hat b)}_{=\operatorname{diam}(E)}+d(b,y)\leq\operatorname{diam}(E)+\varepsilon.$$
Taking supremum over $x,y\in\operatorname{cl}(E)$, one has that $$\operatorname{diam}(\operatorname{cl}(E))=\sup_{x,y\in\operatorname{cl} E}d(x,y)\leq\operatorname{diam}(E)+\varepsilon.$$ Since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, it follows that $$\operatorname{diam}(\operatorname{cl}(E))\leq\operatorname{diam}(E).$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $diam(\overline{E})>diam(E)$. Then $diam(\overline{E}-E)> 0$. Therefore, for every  $p,q\in \overline{E} - E$ , $\exists d\in \mathbb R\geq 0$ such that $d(p,q)< d$. Now consider the following: By the definition of closure,  $\overline{E}=E\cup E'$ where $E' = \{p| p \text{ is an accumulation point of E}\}$. Therefore, $p,q \in \overline{E}- E $ are accumulation points of $E$ where $p,q\notin E$. Clearly, there exists an open ball where $q\in B_d(p)\subset \overline{E} -E$.  Let $N_p(q)$ be a neihborhood of $p$ containing $q$ in $\overline{E}-E$. Then since $p$ is an accumulation point of $E$, there exists $z\in E$ such that $z\in B_l(p)\subset N_p(q)$. where $B_l(p)\subset N_p(q)$ where $l\leq d\in \mathbb R \geq 0 $.

Let $r= diam(E)$. Then:

$$d(p,q) \leq d(p,z) + d(z,q) = l + d = r.  $$

But this means $diam(\overline{E}) \leq diam(E)$ and we have a contradiction! Q.E.D.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have a question about this,  by your claim that "there exist an open ball $B_d(p) \subseteq $ cl($E$) - $E$ , since $p$ is an accumulation point of $E$, then $ B_d(p)$ contain a point $x$ in $E$ but then this will violate the fact that $B_d(p) \subseteq $ cl($E$) - $E$ ?? I'm sorry if I don't understand your idea.

Comment: @Khoata cl(E) - E is defined as the set of all points in the closure of E which does not contain any points of E i.e. cl(E) $\cap E^c$. Therefore if the open ball contains a point of E, then the ball is not a subset of cl(E)-E and we have a contradiction. Clear?

Comment: thank you for the reply, but how do you know cl($E$) - $E$ is an open set so that you can conclude for any point in the set there is an open ball contain in that set?? I know closure of a set is closed but I don't see how that leads to that fact.

Comment: I kept thinking about what I asked you yesterday but I still don't get how you can conclude there is an open ball in cl($E$) $- E$, but here is my counterexample, suppose $E$ is the interval $ (0,1) \in \mathbb{R} $, then you can see that cl($E$) $ - E$= $ \{0,1 \} $ and by def, diam(cl($E$)) $= 1 - 0 = 1 > 0$.  But as you can see there is no open ball contain in cl($E$) $ - E$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there exists $x, y \in \bar{E}$ such that $r = \rho(x, y) - \text{diam}(E) > 0$. Then there exists $u \in E \cap B(x, \frac{r}{2})$ and $v \in E \cap B(y, \frac{r}{2})$ (since $x, y \in \bar{E}$). Therefore
\begin{align*}
&& \rho(x, y) - \rho(u, v) \leq \rho(x, u) +   \rho(y, v) &< r = \rho(x, y) - \text{diam}(E) && \\
\Longrightarrow
&& \text{diam}(E) &< \rho(u, v), &&
\end{align*}
a clear contradiction. Thus, $\rho(x, y) \leq \text{diam}(E)$ for all $x, y \in \bar{E}$ and so $\text{diam}(\bar{E}) \leq \text{diam}(E)$.